# Analytical proof with medians through a $\Delta ABC$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

Given are $\Delta ABC$ with $A(-2,2); B(6,0); C(2,-4)$

**a)** Prove analytically that the medians of $\Delta ABC$ go through 1 point and look for the coordinates of the centroid $Z$.

Side question How does one get equations of the medians?

I've tried calculating the median that goes through B but I get the negation of what it should be i.e. $y=\frac{-1}{6}x+1$

Comment: You don't need to find the equation of the lines that form the triangle. Rather find midpoints of edges. Now show that the midpoint of an edge, the vertex opposite it and point $\frac{a+b+c}{3}$ are collinear. by equating their slopes. As all three medians go through common point $\frac{a+b+c}{3}$, you have proved $(a)$. Now for $b$, use distance to the vertex from $Z$ and to the midpoint of edge and show they are in ratio $2:1$

Comment: If you don't want to cheat using the knowledge that the intersection point is $\frac{a+b+c}{3}$, find equations of medians and find their common intersection point

Comment: I have calculated the midpoints of each edge but when I try to calculate the equation of the median let's call it $|NB|$ I'm getting stuck. I get something that is the negation of what it should be.

Comment: can you pls edit the question and show what you get?

Comment: I've reduced it to the first part of the question. Apologies I've made a sign typo. I now have the right answer.

Comment: The midpoint of $AC$ is $(0, -1)$ so the equation of median through $B (6, 0)$ is $y - 0 = \frac{0 - (-1)}{6 - 0} (x - 6) \implies 6y = x - 6$

Comment: Agreed, I've got idem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

As you see in figure:

$$x_G=\frac{x_A+x_B+x_C}3=2$$

$$y_G=\frac{y_A+y_B+y_C}3=-0.66$$

Find coordinates of midpoints of the sides. The coordinates of G must satisfy equation of lines from  each vertex and midpoint of it's opposite side.

You can also find the mirror of each vertex about midpoint of opposite side. As can be seen in figure the mirrors of two vertices must be col-linear with third vertex which is easy to check.This is possible only if all medians go through one point( a property of medians).